# Package-by-feature when creating a library

Tags: java, structure, package

As I understand it, it's generally recommended to package by feature rather than by layer. This promotes higher levels of abstraction and modularity between classes.

I can understand how this works in regular non-library applications with obvious features (`registration`, `security`, etc), but this is really hard to apply when looking at static utility libraries.

For example, take a look [Google Guava's packaging structure](https://github.com/google/guava/tree/master/guava/src/com/google/common). As it is a library, it is hard to categorize the features of the library into packages. There is an `annotations` package, a `networking` package, etc. This feels like a bit of a grey-zone to me as it isn't packaged in an explicit format?

What is the general consensus when packaging by feature for something which consists of unique utility classes with no common feature (such as a library/API)?

And on a side note, is there any sense in packaging by layer if your project is split into multiple modules, each module representing a feature?